cannot get dns to route over wireguard connection to AWS VPC's DNS
TL;DR:
DNS appears inaccessible through otherwise working wireguard tunnel.  DNS works from within the VPC.  Why no DNS worky work over the wire?

So, you can just point a private Route53 Hosted Zone at a VPC and poof you get internal DNS.  I did that.  From within my VPC, it works:
$ hostname
ip-10-99-11-96.ec2.internal
$ dig +short g.ops.internal
10.99.11.123
$ dig +short @10.99.0.2 g.ops.internal
10.99.11.123

Also, from within the VPC, I can nc direct to the DNS "server/service/whatever-this-magical-AWS-thing-is".  It exists. Yay:
nc -zv 10.99.0.2 53
Ncat: Version 7.93 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.99.0.2:53.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.03 seconds.

If I introduce Wireguard to the mix and connect to it from OSX (without any DNS configuration):
[Interface]
PrivateKey = XXX
Address = 10.0.0.5/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXX
AllowedIPs = 10.99.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/24
Endpoint = 123.123.123.123:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

Then, I can connect to wireguard and I can get to real, non-DNS hosts directly from my laptop:
laptop5000$ nc -zv 10.99.41.126 22
Connection to 10.99.41.126 port 22 [tcp/ssh] succeeded!

But, I cannot dig, or nc the DNS host from my laptop.
dig +timeout=5 +short @10.99.0.2 g.ops.internal
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

nc -zv 10.99.0.2 53
# hangs forever

....why?
At this point I have 22, 53(UDP/TCP), 51820 in the security group all open through to this box. The 53 maybe doesn't make sense, because DNS isn't actually on this host.  10.99.0.2 is off elsewhere in nebulous AWS-land.
I wonder if it has something to do with the Interface (10.0.0.1/24) that wireguard creates.  Presumably AWS knows nothing about this network, so maybe routing from external -> 10.0.0.5 -> AWS land gets dorked up a bit?

Side question (since it's all the same setup):  If I add any DNS config to my wireguard client config then OSX routes all traffic across the wireguard tunnel. (This is confirmed by looking at /etc/resolv.conf).  I'd prefer to keep internet traffic local and only route designated domains across the tunnel.  Is that possible?
